# Adding files to Google music without Music Manager

Tags: google-play-music

I would like to add some MP3 files from my computer to Google music. [Music Manager](http://www.google.com/support/music/bin/answer.py?answer=1229972) doesn't seem to let you select specific files to add. Additionally, I don't really like Music Manager to say the least. Is it possible to upload files from my computer without Music Manager?

Comment: I bet this is still not possible, almost 1 year later. But you can "upload by playlist" now.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I have a simple answer. You can copy specific songs to a separate folder. and select just that folder to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If it's not already visible, open the menu by clicking the hamburger menu.

[image]

Scroll to the bottom of the menu.

[image: bottom of Google Play Music menu]

Click "Upload music". You'll get a dialog box. You can either drag-and-drop music files onto that box (assuming a modern enough browser<sup>1</sup>) or you can click "Select from your computer" to get a more traditional file select dialog.

[image: Add music dialog]

---

<sup>1</sup> I use Google Chrome. These screen shots are from version *47.0.2526.106 m*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/musicalpha/obojocfchdgdpgcigcdhdnlakfcbbgfn/) will help you.

> Upload files to your Google Music account without installing the Google Music manager.

[image: screen shot]